# Tracking Page hits in HTML

Tags: html

I am newbie in html. I want to track the page hits. But now getting how can I proceed for the same. Please suggested. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can track them globally only from a server. Do you have any server, and what is the platform? Is PHP Supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can track them globally only from a server.

#### Case 1: When your server supports PHP

Do you have any server, and what is the platform? If your server supports PHP, then it is easy for you. Just add this code to your browser, where you wanna get the hit counts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="hits.php"></script>
```

And the code for the `hits.php` is as follows:

```
<?php
    $counts = ("counter.txt");
    $hits = file($counts);
    $hits[0] ++;
    $fp = fopen($counts, "w");
    fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
    fclose($fp);
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    echo "document.write('" . $hits[0] . "');";
?>
```

The PHP file has a file `counter.txt` that stores the number of times, the page has been accessed. It increases a count by one and gives out the count this way:

```
document.write('100');
```

---

#### Case 2: When you don't have a server, but just want to track the hits.

There are many services that offer **free** hit counters, and a few of them are:

- [Digits](http://www.digits.com/)
- [OneStat Free Hit Counter](http://www.onestatfree.com/)
- [Amazing Counters](http://www.amazingcounters.com/)

Comment: @Praveen Nicely explained (Case 1). Btw Is there any way to avoid increment of counter when we refresh the page? i.e., It should count only when the page is opened not refresh.

Comment: @Kirataka Sure. Just use sessions to keep track of the same user. Remember, this might not work if the user closes the browser or invalidates session somehow.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to store your count somewhere so that you can access it, increase it for every visit to your site.

So the best place is at the server side from where all you files will be accessed.

And for storage , retrieval and modification of such information you need to learn [server side scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) like [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) [ASP.NET](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/default.asp) etc.